# Google Maps Client ID or API Key

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In building a Google Maps application for a client that has Google Maps API for Business they have a "Client ID", but not an "API Key". Is it as simple as them logging into their Google account and generating an "API Key", or because they have Google Maps API for Business, they actually will only have a "Client ID" without the ability to generate an "API Key"?

I should note that I do not have access to their Google account. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client has the Google Maps APIs Premium Plan, they can [use either their client ID or an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#authentication-and-authorization) in their requests. Do note that [some Maps APIs are required to use an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/faq#client-key-diffs), such as the webservice Places SDK and the Mobile SDKs. If your client wants to use those APIs, then they will need to log into the [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) into their project and create an API key. If they don't have access to Console, they (or you) will have to go to the [Cloud Support Portal](https://google.secure.force.com) and log a support case with Google to gain access.

Comment: Thank you very much, Preston. This helped communicate to the Client what our next steps were.